# Correct use of Pacemaker's ocf-tester with OCF resource agents

Tags: drbd, pacemaker, linux-ha

I have got a setup with DRBD, Corosync, and Pacemaker in which Pacemaker should mount a file system atop a DRBD block device on different cluster nodes, depending on nodes' availabilies. The setup is not yet fully working, therefore I try testing Pacemaker's resource agent for DRBD, `ocf::linbit:drbd`, with `ocf-tester`.

If I try like so (`drbd_res` is the name of the DRBD resource in Pacemaker; `r1` is the name of the resource in `/etc/drbd.conf`)

```
sudo ocf-tester -n drbd_res -o drbd_resource="r1"\
    /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/linbit/drbd monitor
```

I get this error message:

```
Beginning tests for /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/linbit/drbd...
/usr/sbin/ocf-tester: 226: /usr/sbin/ocf-tester: xmllint: not found
* rc=127: Your agent produces meta-data which does not conform to ra-api-1.dtd
* rc=6: Validation failed.  Did you supply enough options with -o ?
WARNING: You may be disappointed: This RA is intended for pacemaker
1.0 or better! 
ERROR: meta parameter misconfigured, expected clone-max -le 2, but found unset. 
Aborting tests
```

So my question is this: How exactly can I manually invoke (i.e. test) OCF resource agents with `ocf-tester`? For the given example, I would expect the execution to complete with one of the [prescribed](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/OCF_Resource_Agents) return values. I am using DRBD 8.4.3 and Pacemaker 1.1.16 on Debian.

Comment: Re: `xmllint not found`: `apt-get install libxml2-utils`. Also, I think, you should set the `clone-max` param.

Comment: @gf_ How can I set `clone-max`?

Comment: It's described in the man page (of ocf-tester), and you did use the syntax already for `drbd_resource...`.

Comment: `clone-max` is an `ms` (fancy cloned resource) meta option... you cannot define that in a `primitive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error tells:

```
Beginning tests for /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/linbit/drbd...
/usr/sbin/ocf-tester: 226: /usr/sbin/ocf-tester: xmllint: not found
```

It doesn't have `xmllint` to test the agent, so first install it using: `apt-get install libxml2-utils`

Then it should work fine. Hope is helps. :)
All the best. :)

Answer (score 2):

DRBD can exist in many states, and therefore requires an additional master/slave set to be defined in Pacemaker that references the primitive which uses the `ocf:libit:drbd` resource agent. Resource agents that require master/slave sets typically cannot be tested using `ocf-tester`.

However, I can assure you, the `ocf:linbit:drbd` resource agent is OCF compliant.

Comment: Thx. OCF compliance was not in doubt. I am wondering how I can perhaps "debug" a setup multiple with resource agents and constraints between them that is not yet behaving as expected overall.

Comment: Create a new question and tag it with Pacemaker and DRBD; I'll see it and try to help if I can ;)

Comment: @MattKereczman Thanks for the insights, +1.

Comment: @MattKereczman Problem solved: I had apparently mistyped the name of a resource in `crm configure`.